# Prevent scroll when click on a tag with href in tab- Liferay

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, liferay

I create some porlets in Liferay. In portlet I use tab

```
<ul class='etabs'>
    <li class='tab'><a id="scrolltest" href="#aging">ABC</a></li>
    <li class='tab'><a href="#exception">EDV</a></li>
    <li class='tab'><a href="#adjust">SDF</a></li>
</ul>
```

It work well. But my problem is When I click on tab menu, Chrome scroll automatically so tab menu is hidden. 
Then I use this code.

```
$('#scrolltest').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;

});
```

but my code does not work with chrome. It still scroll.
How can I prevent it.

Comment: Try adding `e.stopPropagation();`

Answer (score 0):

Use AUI tab. Goto [AUI TabView](http://alloyui.com/examples/tabview/) for details.

```
<div id="myTab">

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#tab-1">Tab #1</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab-2">Tab #2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-3">Tab #3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-pane">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus dicta aspernatur beatae fuga neque cupiditate laudantium itaque pariatur deleniti tenetur modi voluptatem animi sunt eligendi nisi corporis expedita quaerat facilis.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2">
      <p>Doloremque beatae rem voluptate nulla perspiciatis atque laudantium nihil impedit molestiae fuga veritatis quibusdam nam maiores aliquid. Deserunt dolorum quas temporibus enim ex nihil nemo perspiciatis. Nisi deserunt rem id pariatur in nostrum?</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-3" class="tab-pane">
      <p>Aliquid ipsum asperiores alias temporibus autem impedit soluta ut id iure explicabo veritatis consectetur debitis eaque recusandae odit quas nobis maxime saepe. Incidunt amet obcaecati. Ducimus soluta unde repellat laboriosam fuga modi rem itaque!</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
AUI().use(
  'aui-tabview',
  function(A) {
    new A.TabView(
      {
        srcNode: '#myTab'
      }
    ).render();
  }
);
</script>
```

It worked for me.